# Integer to Script with a Variable in a URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am sorry, as this question may have been asked before, but I could not find an answer that worked in my situation.
I am new to Objective-C, and I am not entirely knowledgable, so I apologize beforehand in the case that I seem like I am not amazing ;)

So, I have a webView, and everyday, the url changes.  Ex: on April 30th the url is http://example.com/mylinkApr30
Using dates, I made a variable (sorry if my terminology is off :\ ), and the url ends in %d everything works just fine, except when it comes to month.  The months are not in the typical MM form, they are in a shortened text, with the three first letters of the month name.  Ex: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.

I have the month integer working, and it writes as 1,2,3 etc.
How should I go about changing that to Jan, Feb, Mar?

Is there a different way I could go about this??
I can confirm the days are working, I have tested it with having 1 variable, and using Apr at the end of the link.

Here is my code, so it is easier for you to understand what I am asking.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Balmoral";
NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  
NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | 
NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
//NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
//NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
//NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
//NSInteger second = [dateComponents second]; 

NSString *baseURLStr = @"http://wwww.WebsiteHere.com/Apr";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURLStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.ashx", day]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
[NSCalendar release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `NSDateFormatter` class, something like:

```
int month = 3;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", month]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSString *monthString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"MONTH STRING %@", monthString);
```

monthString should be "Mar"

Comment: I do like this, do the Apple docs have a listing of the date formats? I did a quick search in conjunction with `NSDateFormatter` but came up with nothing.

Comment: Adam almost has it.  You can simplify his answer a little since you're using the current date.  You don't need to do lines 4 and 5.  Switch line 7 to "NSString *monthString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];" and you're good.  This will replace all of you calendar stuff.

Comment: @Ryan Unicode Technical Standard #35 is used for the patterns, http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @McCygnus Thanks, I actually had no idea that all that was standardized.

Comment: One last question, I have another link, and it works the exact same, but instead of the first three letters of the month, it is the whole month name.  Ex: January, March, April, October    How should I go about this?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it.  Just need's 4 M's  Thanks again, you guys are a a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

,Since you are not using the standard MM format you cannot use NSDateFormatter. You need a switch for all 12 months.

```
NSString * monthString = nil;
switch (month)
{
case 1:
monthString = @"Jan";
break;
case 2:
...
}
```

Then modify your own code:

```
NSString *baseURLStr = @"http://wwww.WebsiteHere.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseURLStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%d.ashx", monthString, day]];
```

EDIT:
Ryan is right. his solution is better.

Comment: This is a little unnecessarily verbose to be entirely honest.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, and likely naive, approach would be to have an array with the text you want:

```
NSArray *months = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jan", @"Feb", nil];
```

This would allow you to get the string by:

```
NSString *monthString = [months objectAtIndex:month];
```

Comment: I am using this code, is is very easy for me to implement into what I have now.   Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark at least one answer as your answer. Although I would still give that honor to @adam. His code makes use of actual Cocoa Touch whereas mine is "hackish" at best. Still, a vote up can't hurt! ;)

Comment: I will, don't worry. I tested this method by using a tinyurl to Apr30  the link did not load, even though I had filled out the NSArray correctly.  When I set *monthString to @"Apr" it did work though.  What could be wrong?

Comment: If it was all correct, I would imagine it would work. I can't think of anything that would prevent a simple concatenated string from working correctly. I would probably post that as a separate question if you continue to have issues, providing your full (revised) code.